# Need to implement conditional dropdown in excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have below requirement tried multiple solutions using several formulas like INDEX, SMALL, etc

[image]

```
IF type = int then add that id in dropdown.
Please help if anyone knows the solution.
```

Comment: If that list will be always the same, then check https://exceljet.net/dependent-dropdown-lists. If not, your only solution will be with VBA

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns  list data is coming from database everytime